# comparing text in cells in vba using strcomp

Tags: vba, excel

I have a matrix of rows and columns with data as string not integer. I have a reference cell which I want to compare with the a particular cell in each row. I have the following code.

```
`Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
With Sheets("Sheet1")
str2 = Cells(1, 14).Value
For j = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
           str1 = Cells(j, 2).Value
           result = StrComp(str1, str2, vbBinaryCompare)
           If result = 0 Then
             .Range(.Cells(j, 1), .Cells(j, 12)).Copy
             ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 14).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
           End If
Next j
End With`
```

The problem is it is telling me that every comparison is true. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could it be due to the lack of a reference to the sheet your `str1` is on? Make sure to explicitly give the sheet whenever you use a range like `Cells()`.

Comment: @BruceWayne You are doing justice to your username. Savior!!

Comment: Yeah, that's always something to be careful of.  Note that you do not need the first `...Activate` line.  That's probably what's partially confusing you/your code. You `Activated` the Sheet2, but then use `With Sheets("Sheet1")`...so any time it used `Cells()` unqualified, it was looking at `Sheet2()`.  Also, replace the `ActiveSheet.Cells(...)` with `Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2,14)...` (assuming it's "Sheet2" you want). :D